# parsing dataframe columns containing functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parsing

Python/pandas newbie here.  The csv file I'm trying to work with has been populated with data that looks something like this:

```
A                                                      B            C       D
Option1(item1=12345, item12='string', item345=0.123)   2020-03-16   1.234   Option2(item4=123, item56=234, item678=345)
```

I'd like it to look like this:

```
item1   item12     item345   B            C      item4   item56   item678
12345   'string'   0.123     2020-03-16   1.234  123     234      345
```

In other words, I want to replace columns A and D with new columns headed by what's on the left of the equal sign, using what's to the right of the equal sign as the corresponding value, and with the Option1() and Option2() parts and the commas stripped out. The columns that don't contain functions should be left as is.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Actually, at this point, I'd settle for any old way, elegant or not; I've found various ways of dealing with this situation if, say, there were dicts populating columns, but nothing to help me pick it apart if there are functions there. Trying to search for the answer only gives me a bunch of results for how to *apply* functions to dataframes.

Comment: Your question is confusing. You say it's coming form a csv file, so is the dataframe populated with the string representation of the function? `"Option1(item1=12345, item12='string', item345=0.123)"`? Because that would just be a matter of string parsing to get it in a dict format.

Comment: Can you post 2 or 3 of the list used to create your df?

Comment: @G.Anderson sorry for the confusion; I was trying to summarize, and I may have left out too much. I don't know if I can consider it a string in context: I'm using ib-insync to get option chains; this is a simplified version of how that data looks.  With ib-insync, the philosophy is to "to convert from and to a dataframe 'at the edges' and not to use it as an internal data structure."  I *do* need to use it as an internal data structure, as far as I can tell, because I need a tidy csv file to pass to matlab. Maybe if I knew more I could make use of the function rather than just string parsing?

Comment: @JackFleeting Are you asking for more rows?  I just made row 0 up; you can type random numbers just as easily!  ;) The actual data is an option chain, the first 2 rows of which are too long for a comment by 2096 characters.

Comment: No, not more rows. I can indeed make them up myself, which I did. But other problems came up, so I was looking for couple of examples of the **source** data from which those rows are extracted. It may be possible to solve part of the problem by changing the extraction method, resulting in rows which are easier to parse in the way you want them to be parsed.

Comment: @JackFleeting Ahh, thanks. Probably best to send you to this: nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/master/… , which is what I'm working my way through. I've saved off the results of util.df(tickers) as a csv file.

Comment: Your link is invalid...

Comment: @JackFleeting Derp.  This should work: https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/erdewit/ib_insync/blob/master/notebooks/option_chain.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your functions always have the same arguments, this should work.

You can read the csv with (if separators are 2 or more spaces, that's what I get when I paste your question example):

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv',sep='[\s]{2,}', index_col=False, engine='python')
```

If your dataframe is `df`:

```
# break out both sides of the equal sign in function into columns
A_vals = df['A'].str.extractall(r'([\w\d]+)=([^,\)]*)')

# get rid of the multi-index and put the values after '=' into columns
A_converted = A_vals.unstack(level=-1)[1]

# set column names to values before '='
A_converted.columns = list(A_vals.unstack(level=-1)[0].values[0])

# same thing for 'D'
D_vals = df['D'].str.extractall(r'([\w\d]+)=([^,\)]*)')
D_converted = D_vals.unstack(level=-1)[1]
D_converted.columns = list(D_vals.unstack(level=-1)[0].values[0])

# join everything together
df = A_converted.join(df.drop(['A','D'], axis=1)).join(D_converted)
```

Some clarification on the regex `'([\w\d]+)=([^,\)]*)'` has two capture groups (each part in parens):

Group 1 `([\w\d]+)` is one or more characters (`+`)  that are word characters `\w` or numbers `\d`.

`=` between groups.

Group 2 `([^,\)]*)` is 0 or more characters (`*`) that are not (`^`) a comma `,` or paren `\)`.

Comment: Excellent, clear answer.  Because I actually had more than just columns A & D that needed fixing, I wound up going with `pd.concat` to put the new columns together.  For my newb learning purposes, could/should I have used `join` instead?  In my short time spent with it, I couldn't figure out how to rewrite the "join everything together" line properly to accommodate 5 different new columns (although I did properly drop each old one). The results from using `pd.concat` work fine, just trying to learn!

Comment: The pandas docs have a good description of concat, merge, and join [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html) where it seems like it's just preference since they have the same defaults. Also, what would it take to get this marked as the answer to the question?

Comment: Welp, it is in place and working, so yep, I most certainly should!

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for something along these lines:

```
contracts = ["Option(conId=384688665, symbol='SPX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20200116', strike=3205.0, right='P', multiplier='100', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='SPX   200117P03205000', tradingClass='SPX')",    
"Option(conId=12345678, symbol='DJX', lastTradeDateOrContractMonth='20200113', strike=1205.0, right='P', multiplier='200', exchange='SMART', currency='USD', localSymbol='DJXX   333117Y13205000', tradingClass='DJX')"]

new_conts = []
columns = []

for i in range (len(contracts)):
    mod = contracts[i].replace('Option(','').replace(')','')
    contracts[i] = mod    
    new_cont = contracts[i].split(',')
    new_conts.append(new_cont)

for contract in new_conts:
    column = []
    for i in range (len(contract)):
        mod = contract[i].split('=')
        contract[i] = mod[1]
        column.append(mod[0])
    columns.append(column)

print(len(columns[0]))
df = pd.DataFrame(new_conts,columns=columns[0])
df
```

Output:

```
    conId   symbol  lastTradeDateOrContractMonth    strike  right   multiplier  exchange    currency    localSymbol     tradingClass
0   384688665   'SPX'   '20200116'  3205.0  'P'     '100'   'SMART'     'USD'   'SPX 200117P03205000'   'SPX'
1   12345678    'DJX'   '20200113'  1205.0  'P'     '200'   'SMART'     'USD'   'DJXX 333117Y13205000'  'DJX'
```

Obviously you can then delete unwanted columns, change names, etc.

Comment: excellent, and I learned from it, but I already got the regex answer working and in place, so I'll have to use what I learned elsewhere!